# Losing connection to Cloud SQL while performing a mysqldump

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Recently, I've started seeing issues performing a mysqldump on a Cloud SQL instance. It runs for about 20 minutes, then afterwards it fails with the following error:

```
 mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table "table3" at row: 3518748
```

Then, if I look in the MySQL error log on the CloudSQL console, I see the following:

```
"2018-06-29T14:46:11.143774Z 4320729 [Note] Aborted connection 4320729 to db: 'bobs_db' user: 'bob' host: '1.2.3.4' (Got timeout writing communication packets)"
```

Here is the command I run:

```
mysqldump -h 1.1.1.1 --port=3306 -u bob -pbobs_pwd --net_buffer_length=16m --compatible=ansi --skip-extended-insert --compact --single-transaction --skip-triggers --where="created_at < '2018-06-29 00:00:00' OR updated_at < '2018-06-29 00:00:00'" bobs_db "table1 table2 table3 table4"
```

Seems everything I read around this issue points to making the net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout bigger but CloudSQL doesn't provide access to those variables from what I can tell.

I'm running with the default database flags except for the following one:

```
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
```

Comment: You didn't show it, but what are you doing with the output of `mysqldump`?  Piping it to a file?  Or piping it to a compression program?  Or something else?

Comment: This is very generic error, it can mean a lot of things. By the way you can set the net_write_timeout using Cloud Shell to login to MySQL instance.

Comment: It could be that you Cloud SQL instance is running out of memory during the export. Select your instance [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances) and check the *Memory Usage*. You can scrub all sensitive data and share the screenshot with us.

Comment: It seems to have been the net_write_timeout

Comment: @julsemaan it seems you may have found the solution for your question. May I ask you to post it as an answer?

Comment: @julsemaan Would you mind posting your solution, and accepting it if possible? For future reference of the community.

Comment: @GonçaloAlbino and @Mangu there is a flag `net_write_timeout` in Cloud SQL that you can bump to a larger value.